# The new name 'Categories' is already in use as a OBJECT name and would cause a duplicate that is not permitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Use This Code

```
using (var db=new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var q = db.Categories.ToList();
        }
```

And Get Error:

The new name 'Categories' is already in use as a OBJECT name and would cause a duplicate   that is not permitted.

Comment: Have you recently changed a name of context or any tables? This error seem to be more frequently appearing after a name change.

Comment: No, but  the problem was fixed when  database clear،thanks

Comment: It's always nice when problems get fixed :)